# AMD Graphics Drivers not available for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, opengl

I'm trying to upgrade the OpenGL driver from 1.1 to 2.0 (or the latest version). I'm currently using [this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) to select the appropiate download, but when choosing *Integrated Motherboard Graphics* > *Radeon 3xxx Series* > *Radeon 3000 Series* there's no Windows 8 option (only from XP to 7).

Isn't Windows 8 supported? How should I proceed?

Comment: You can try your luck with the Windows 7 driver. In case it doesn't work, maybe Windows Update will find appropriate driver.

Comment: Of course it is.  They just ended support because Windows 8.1 is a free upgrade and basically the only version Microsoft will support going forward.

Answer (score 2):

**PLEASE READ THE README files on the AMD site**

Direct from AMD:  http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

```
Starting with AMD Catalyst™ 14.6 Beta, AMD will no longer support Windows 8.0 (and the WDDM 1.2 driver)
Windows 8.0 users should upgrade (for free) to Windows 8.1 to take advantage of the new features found in the AMD Catalyst 14.7 RC driver
AMD Catalyst 14.4 will remain available for users who wish to remain on Windows 8
    A future AMD Catalyst release will allow for the WDDM 1.1 (Windows 7 driver) to be installed under Windows 8.0 for those users unable to upgrade to Windows 8.1
```